# Как передать русские символы/строки в функции с++?

Tags: c++, функции, консоль

Возникла необходимость написать функцию, которая принимает строку и кое-как с ней работает. Тонкость в том, что строка будет состоять полностью из русских символов.
В начале метода main() написал следующее:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
```

В консоли русские буквы прекрасно считываются и отображаются, но в функцию передаются крокозябры: [image: пример проблемы]
Возможно ли как-нибудь передать в функцию русское слово?

Comment: Если кодировка дебаггера не совпадает с кодировкой информации - то это проблема дебаггера. Меняйте дебаггер. Тут врядли можно чем то помочь, переводите в юникод-кодировку - её дебаггер будет нормально понимать. Самой функции "начхать" в какой кодировке функция, пока не используется "сравнение" и сортировка. это иллюзия что слово в функцию приходит "не в той" кодировке, которую создаёт дебаггер. Надо смотреть на значения байтов (коды символов) - если они те что надо - то всё ок.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Благодарю nick_n_a за подсказку. Проблему решил.
Действительно, при считывании текста консоль отдавала дебаггеру текст в другой кодировке.
Проблема решилась заменой строчки `setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");` на

```
SetConsoleCP(1251);
SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
```

При этом нужно подключить `#include <windows.h>`